# Analysis by SEM in variables with different Likert scale

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, likert

I have a questionnaire that measures two variables. The first variable is measured with 5-point Likert But second variable is measured by questions with 5 and 3 point Likert and dichotomous (YES, NO).
Can we investigate effect of first variables on second with structural equation modeling?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can. The number of points doesn't matter (unless you want to compare the means of the variables).

Comment: Thank you
It is possible to explain more?
This model that has been attached can be run with Amos?

Comment: I can explain more if you have a question. The answer to the question you asked is "yes". (I"m not sure it can be done in Amos appropriately, it's many years since I've used Amos.)

Comment: What is best software to run these models? Should smartPLS be used?

Comment: I would use lavaan or Mplus.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, Sir. But, while calculating the "FML value" (Fitting Maximum Likelihood value), should we use the "Covariance Matrix or Correlation Matrix"?